# Putting Dots onto Owl Carousel Instead of below

Tags: owl-carousel

It seems that by default Owl Carousel puts the dots that represent the each slide under the carousel instead of inside at the bottom. I discovered that I can add negative margin to them and they will go inside the carousel but they are behind it effectively making them useless. I cannot figure out a way to get them to appear on top. Any ideas?

Comment: I have the same question, still searching for a solution..

Comment: Hey man. I know its been a few days but I think I may have solved this by using negative top margins and a higher z-index. Cant remember 100% but I think thats what I did.

Comment: me too :) using negative margin solves the problem. but thank you very much for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Though your problem should be usually be solved with higher `z-index`, you could set the carousel to `position: relative;` and place the dots-div with `position: absolute;`.

Another approach would be to move the `div` with JS/jQuery with `$('.owl-dots')`.

I build an option where the dots get cloned into each slide. Only problem is that you need then also a new `click` and `chanaged` event.

There my approach:

```js
var owl = $('.custom1').owlCarousel({
    animateOut: 'slideOutDown',
    animateIn: 'flipInX',
    items:1,
    margin:30,
    stagePadding:30,
    smartSpeed:450,
    loop: true,
    dots: true,
    autoplay: true,
});

// Clone dots into slide
var dots = $('.owl-dots');
$('h4').after(dots.clone().addClass('owl-dot-clone'));
dots.hide(); // hide orginal dots

// Set active
owl.on('changed.owl.carousel', function (event) {
    var index = event.page.index;
    $('.owl-dot-clone .owl-dot', this).removeClass('active');
    $('.owl-dot-clone', this).each(function () {
        $('.owl-dot', this).eq(index).addClass('active');
    })    
});

// Create on click event for clone
$('.owl-dot-clone .owl-dot').on('click', function () {
    var owl = $(this).closest('.custom1');
    owl.trigger('to.owl.carousel', [$(this).index(), 300]);
});
```

```css
.owl-dots.owl-dot-clone {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/css/docs.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<section id="demos">
<div class="custom1 owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item"><h4>1</h4>
  </div><div class="item"><h4>2</h4>
  </div><div class="item"><h4>3</h4>
  </div><div class="item"><h4>4</h4>
  </div><div class="item"><h4>5</h4>
  </div><div class="item"><h4>6</h4>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this too.

```
var dots = $('.owl-dots').css('position', 'absolute').css('bottom', '5px');
dots.css('left', 'calc(50% - ' + dots.width()/2+'px)');
```